# Adding a "sidebar" within tabular data?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

It's probably pretty easy to do, but I just can't think of anything. Lets say I have a row of data that looks like this:

```
data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
```

and on the side, I need this:

```
a    data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
b    data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
c    data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
d    data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |  data  |
```

Whereas the 'abcd' string is one div/column and fills the height that the table has automatically been given.

So basically a column within rows. Thoughts?

Requirements is that it's a fluid table. It's just a table with rows, nothing more. It's built based on the display: table/table-row/table-header/table-cell methods.

A simplified markup:

```
.data { 
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse
}
    .data header {
        display: table-header-group;
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2B597B
    }
    .data section {
        display: table-row-group
    }
    .data article { 
        display: table-row;
        line-height: 21px;
        padding: 0 3px
    }
    .data span {
        display: table-cell;
        overflow: hidden
    }
```

With:

```
<div class="data">
<header>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
</header>
<section>
    <article>
        <span>one</span>
        <span>two</span>
    </article>
</section>
</div>
```

It has nothing to do w/ incremental data. Just stuff, it could be an empty space.

Comment: Thoughts: a few. Mark-up..? Any requirements, what've you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your "sidebar" a table cell with a rowspan equal to the total number of rows.

> Aside: You'll find plenty of folks who while shed many tears over
>   using a table this way.  My advice: be pragmatic.  Spend your time
>   solving real problems rather than fussing with semantic HTML for the
>   sake of purity.

An example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">the sidebar</td>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "Spend your time solving real problems rather than fussing with semantic HTML for the sake of purity." truly said.

Comment: Do you have an example? I can't wrap my head around that. Tables aren't my thing.

Comment: Use a real `<table>`.  Don't get too clever.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs for cross-browser compatibility, you could use CSS's generated content and counters:

```
td {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 5em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
    counter-reset: tableRowNum;
}

tbody tr {
    counter-increment: tableRowNum;
}

tbody tr:before {
    font-size: 1em;
    content: counter(tableRowNum, lower-alpha);
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/46faQ/1/).

This has, of course, the usual caveats that IE < 8, or 9, is likely to struggle or fail to render the incrementations. It might be worth using JavaScript to add the 'numbers' if you don't want to hard-code an incrementing value into your table.

Plain JavaScript solution (though this assumes an empty `td` element added to each row already and exists *only* to prevent having to hard-code the incrementing numbers):

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    rows[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = i; // zero-based counting.
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/46faQ/2/).

Comment: Updated main question, it's not to do w/ incremental values. But good idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a list since you're using incrementing values.. so:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>stuff</li>
            <li>more stuff</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

etc

the primary list can be given alphabetical incrementation with css value list-style and the secundairy list can be shown inline by using the css property display.. However semantically you should use a table to represent data.. just add a column to the data since the incrementation is kind of like a primary key for each record?

Comment: Updated main question, it's not to do w/ incremental values.